# C++ ifstream and getline

Tags: c++, ifstream, getline

I'm using an old gcc compiler, if that matters (before C++11).

I have a function with the code below:

```
ifstream in(file);
string line;
while (std::getline(in, line))
{

}
```

I just want to make sure that:

1. I do not need to check if the file actually exists, right? Does `getline` know to handle this?
2. There is no need to close the stream in the end because of RAII, right?

Comment: you can get so many examples online. Have you checked those?

Comment: @mfromla I did and saw people closing the stream and also some checking for the failbit, I don't see the reason for this so wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Musmus There's lots of bad code online.

Comment: Yes, `getline` safely does nothing if the stream is not open.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the example given in the C++ reference website [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/).

There are explanations for different versions of it, like C++98 and C++11.

As for answers:

1. `getline()` will fail, and your code won't get into the `while` loop, if it fails to open the file beforehand.
2. As you said, you don't need to close the file because of RAII.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously getline will fail if the file doesn't exist and you will not enter the while loop.

You do not need to close the stream.